# Creating predicate with pre-built string

Tags: nspredicate

Is there a way to create an nspredicate directly from a pre-formatted string without calling predicateWithFormat?  The final string would look something like:

`(inpatient=1) AND (dischargedate!=<null>) AND ((attending=SMITH) OR (admitting=SMITH) OR (consulting contains[cd] SMITH) OR (attending=JONES) OR (admitting=JONES) OR (consulting contains[cd] JONES))`

```
    NSMutableString *preds = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    NSArray *provs = [self.providerCode componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    for (NSString *prov in provs) {
        [preds appendFormat:@" (attending=%@) OR (admitting=%@) OR (consulting contains[cd] %@) ", prov, prov, prov];
    }
    NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(inpatient=%@) AND (dischargedate!=%@) AND (%@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool: self.inpatients], [NSNull null], preds];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:final]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to modify the format string slightly.

Instead of doing:

```
[preds appendFormat:@" (attending = %@)", prov];
```

You'd need to do:

```
[preds appendFormat:@" (attending = '%@')", prov];
```

Note the use of single-quotes around the `%@` modifier.  That's how the predicate knows it's a constant value.

However, even if you go this route, you're still stuck using `predicateWithFormat:`, which you appear to want to avoid.  You'll also likely have issues with how you're using `NSNull` in the format string.

I would recommend doing something more like this:

```
NSArray *provs = [self.providerCode componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];

NSMutableArray *providerPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attending = $prov OR admitting = $prov OR consulting CONTAINS[cd] $prov"];
for (NSString *prov in provs) {
  NSDictionary *substitutions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:prov forKey:@"prov"];
  NSPredicate *p = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:substitutions];
  [providerPredicates addObject:p];
}

NSPredicate *final = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inpatient = 1 AND dischargedate != nil"];

if ([providerPredicates count] > 0) {
  NSPredicate *providers = nil;
  if ([providerPredicates count] > 1) {
    providers = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:providerPredicates];
  } else {
    providers = [providerPredicates objectAtIndex:0];
  }

  final = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:final, providers, nil]];
}
```

This is using a couple different neat things:

1. Predicate variables.  You parse the format string `@"attending = $prov OR admitting = $prov OR consulting CONTAINS[cd] $prov"` once, and then simply substitute in new values for `$prov` each time you have a different provider
2. Constructing compound predicates.  You use some class methods on `NSCompoundPredicate` to turn multiple predicates into a single, grouped `OR` or `AND` predicate.

Comment: @user680891 glad to hear it! to mark my answer as accepted, click on the checkmark underneath the up/down vote arrows.